# Minikube with VirtualBox start not working on MacOS Monterey

Tags: macos, kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube, macos-monterey

I have a Minikube K8s cluster that I have been using for a while, but after updating to the latest MacOS Monterey, Minikube fails to start with the following error.

`Unable to start the VM: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage startvm minikube --type headless failed:`

Answer (score 0):

So apparently VirtualBox has a bug with Monterey, so I used docker as the driver

`docker system prune`
`minikube delete`
`minikube start --driver=docker`

*Be careful while using the prune and delete commands as it'll delete your cluster and unused containers, networks, etc*